# Centering contents of a div - using CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, css

I have the following source in a user control:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelParametersList" CssClass="AccessReportParameterControls"></asp:Panel>

<div class = "buttonpanel">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View Report" 
    onclick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Back" 
    onclick="Button2_Click"></asp:Button>
</div>
```

In the header of the containing aspx page I am adding css styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ReportViewer_AccessReportViewer { position:absolute; top:50px; }
    .ReportViewer_AccessReportViewer_noparams { position:absolute; top:0px; }
    .AccessReportParameterControls {width: 100%; background-color: #E4E4EC; padding: 5px; }
    .ParameterContainer {width: 100%;}
    .ParameterControlLabel {padding:0, 10, 0, 10;}
    .AccessReportParameters {width: 100%;}
    .buttonpanel {margin:0 auto; }

</style>
```

I am trying to center the contents of the button panel div but am having no luck.....any ideas?

Comment: Edit your title, there's no relation between your question title and body!

Comment: @user -- accept the answer if it fixes/solves your problem!!

Comment: @Vivek -> I seriously get annoyed at people like you who have 177 reputation telling people who have used the site more than enough to figure out how it works, to accept an answer if it helps. Stop wasting pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For centering content in a div

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: Agree, also you can add margin:0 auto so it would be `.buttonpanel{text-align:center;margin:0 auto}`

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class = "parent">
    <button />
</div>
```

**Style:**

```
.parent{
    text-align:center;
}
```

This is all you need to do. Set the `text-align` to `center` in any parent container and the `inline` elements will follow the rule.

As a good practice I would advice you to place your styles in a different `style.css` file and place this in your .asp files:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```